# Почему при использовании класса selectpicker для элемента типа select не добавляются артибуты Options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap-selectpicker

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь при создании формы добавить артибуты Options для элемента типа select

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select id="main_selectpicker" class="selectpicker  show-tick form-control"  data-live-search="true" data-size="15"/>
```

попробовал так

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
$.getJSON('Forward?URL=items.jsp', function (jsondata) {
...
                var main_selectpicker = document.getElementById("main_selectpicker");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.setAttribute("value", jsondata.items[i].name);
                option.text = jsondata.items[i].name;
                main_selectpicker.appendChild(option);
...
    });
</script>
```

и вот так

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
$.getJSON('Forward?URL=items.jsp', function (jsondata) {
...
$('#main_selectpicker').append('<option value="'+jsondata.items[i].name+'">'+jsondata.imtes[i].name+'</option>');
...
    });
</script>
```

значения не появляются у элемента main_selectpicker

Если же из искомого элемента формы убрать наименование класса selectpicker, то Options появляются.
НО мне нужна эта классификация, как эту проблему решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После любых операций с элементами selectpicker'a (добавления/удаления, включения/выключения элемента) - необходимо вызвать функцию refresh.

```
$('#main_selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

[Из документации](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh)